# How do i split a string from a csv file to a partiqular format in php?

Tags: php, csv, split

I have a csv file with the folowing lines(2 for example):

```
004000001001030212001Y  5372 #0001 N,"1","2","3","4","5","5","0"

004000002001030212001Y  5372 #0001 N,"1","2","3","4","5","5","0"
```

What I want to do is to read the csv file in php and then reformat it in the following way:

```
id   date              lp   Lang    token   cod1   cod2   cod3   cod4   cod5   cod6   cod7  

1    03/02/2012 18:00  2    el      grapto  1      2      3      4      5      5      0

2    03/02/2012 18:00  2    el      grapto  1      2      3      4      5      5      0
```

The id is the 8 and 9th digit. Date is the 13th until 18th digit. And then export it to csv again.

Any help will do.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's `fgetcsv` for stuff like this

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

to get id and date from that long string you could do:

```
$id = substr($longString, 8, 2);
$dateStr = substr($longString, 13, 8);
$date = substr($dateStr, 0, 2) . '/' . substr($dateStr, 2, 2) . '/' . substr($dateStr, 4, 4);
```

Now go and implement :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you get `18:00 2 el grapto` from those inputs, but this will do the other stuff:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
echo "id date Ip Lang token cod1 cod2 cod3 cod4 cod5 cod6 cod7\n";
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $values = explode(",", $line);
    $string = array_shift($values);

    $values = array_map(function($value) { return str_replace("\"", "", $value); }, $values);

    $id = substr($string, 7, 2);

    $date = date_parse_from_format("mdy", substr($string, 12, 6));
    $date = date("m/d/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $date["month"], $date["day"], $date["year"]));

    list(, $ip, $lang, $token) = explode(" ", $string);

    array_unshift($values, $id, $date, $ip, $lang, $token);

    echo implode(" ", $values) ."\n";
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
id date Ip Lang token cod1 cod2 cod3 cod4 cod5 cod6 cod7
01 03/02/2012 5372 #0001 N 1 2 3 4 5 5 0
02 03/02/2012 5372 #0001 N 1 2 3 4 5 5 0
```

Comment: I am geting the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home/Oo4QrE/prog.php on line 8

Comment: If I copy and paste my code into a blank PHP script, I get no errors. There must be an error somewhere else in your code, likely a forgotten semicolon or curly brace. Can you copy-paste your actual code (at least up to line 8) into your question and I can help track it down for you?